# Django IF statement?

Tags: django, if-statement

I have a problem with my code here is template code:

```
    {% for category in categorys %}
<p>
    {{category.name}}      
        {% for gamename in gamenames %}
            {% if gamename.category == category.name  %}
                {{gamename.title}}
            {% else %}
                b
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}      
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and here is model code:

```
class Category(models.Model):

name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
opis=models.TextField(max_length=600)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

class GameName(models.Model):

```
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

and here is output screen:[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oMYX.png)

i checked the gamename.category and is equal to category.name but if statement giving always "else"why when if statement should be true?

Answer (score 2):

`gamename.category` is a `category` object, so try using `gamename.category.name` inside the if statement instead.

Comment: Ty my friend! :)